Speed up query looking for gaps in time series in Mariadb
I have a query (bottom) I run against this table of hourly data that looks for missing records -- where I should "gaps" whenever the time between sequential records is greater than 3600 seconds (or 1 hour) from a record to the next temporally based on Intervaldatetime. It used to perform well enough but is now taking many minutes to run. Any thoughts on how I can speed this up? It's about 100,000 records running on Maria DB 10.6 (Ubuntu 22.04).
CREATE TABLE `electric_use` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Intervaldatetime` timestamp(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `kwh` double(11,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ts` timestamp NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `notes` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq_dt` (`Intervaldatetime`,`kwh`),
  KEY `date_index` (`Intervaldatetime`)

insert into `electric_use` (`id`, `Intervaldatetime`, `kwh`, `ts`, `notes`) values('2000','2014-04-25 13:00:00.000000','1.4730',NULL,NULL);
insert into `electric_use` (`id`, `Intervaldatetime`, `kwh`, `ts`, `notes`) values('2001','2014-04-25 14:00:00.000000','1.6610',NULL,NULL);
insert into `electric_use` (`id`, `Intervaldatetime`, `kwh`, `ts`, `notes`) values('2002','2014-04-25 15:00:00.000000','1.5140',NULL,NULL);
insert into `electric_use` (`id`, `Intervaldatetime`, `kwh`, `ts`, `notes`) values('2003','2014-04-25 16:00:00.000000','1.7070',NULL,NULL);
insert into `electric_use` (`id`, `Intervaldatetime`, `kwh`, `ts`, `notes`) values('2004','2014-04-25 17:00:00.000000','1.7210',NULL,NULL);
insert into `electric_use` (`id`, `Intervaldatetime`, `kwh`, `ts`, `notes`) values('2005','2014-04-25 18:00:00.000000','1.7650',NULL,NULL);
insert into `electric_use` (`id`, `Intervaldatetime`, `kwh`, `ts`, `notes`) values('2006','2014-04-25 19:00:00.000000','2.6490',NULL,NULL);
insert into `electric_use` (`id`, `Intervaldatetime`, `kwh`, `ts`, `notes`) values('2007','2014-04-25 20:00:00.000000','1.6050',NULL,NULL);
insert into `electric_use` (`id`, `Intervaldatetime`, `kwh`, `ts`, `notes`) values('2009','2014-04-25 22:00:00.000000','1.5970',NULL,NULL);
insert into `electric_use` (`id`, `Intervaldatetime`, `kwh`, `ts`, `notes`) values('2010','2014-04-25 23:00:00.000000','2.2840',NULL,NULL);


and here is the query.
SELECT
  `t`.`Intervaldatetime` AS `GapStart`,
  `t`.`NextDateTime`     AS `GapEnd`,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`t`.`Intervaldatetime`,`t`.`NextDateTime`) AS `SizeInSecond`
FROM (SELECT
        `t1`.`Intervaldatetime` AS `Intervaldatetime`,
        (SELECT
           `t2`.`Intervaldatetime`
         FROM `electric_use` `t2`
         WHERE `t2`.`Intervaldatetime` > `t1`.`Intervaldatetime`
         LIMIT 1) AS `NextDateTime`
      FROM `electric_use` `t1`) `t`
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`t`.`Intervaldatetime`,`t`.`NextDateTime`) > 3600)


please describe in English what makes a "missing record"

the innermost select has a limit but no order by; this means the result is ambiguous and often not what you intend

Just updated the original problem statement to make it more clear. So far the missing order by has not resulted in a problem, but I can see the value... I guess I've been lucky so far.

can you have duplicate times?  from your schema it seems so.  if you do, and there's a gap before or after a duplicate, do you need both the duplicates reported?  the current query includes both

I have been using this primitive but faster query to show me duplicate values SELECT electric_use.IntervaldatetimeASIntervaldatetime, COUNT(electric_use.id) AS COUNT(id)FROMelectric_useGROUP BYelectric_use.Intervaldatetime HAVING COUNT(electric_use.id) > 1
Duplicates have not been a problem as I manually correct them in a separate step

You should use LEAD instead of a subselect to find the next time.  This should be much more efficient.
SELECT
  `t`.`Intervaldatetime` AS `GapStart`,
  `t`.`NextDateTime`     AS `GapEnd`,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`t`.`Intervaldatetime`,`t`.`NextDateTime`) AS `SizeInSecond`
FROM (
  SELECT
    Intervaldatetime,
    LEAD(Intervaldatetime) OVER (ORDER BY Intervaldatetime) NextDateTime
  FROM electric_use
) t
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`t`.`Intervaldatetime`,`t`.`NextDateTime`) > 3600

fiddle

Thank you. That's amazing! I'm going to use that in other places. Looking it up this seems  just like what the doctor ordered, "The LEAD function accesses data from a following row in the same result set without the need for a self-join."
My original formulation would run for 9 min 57 seconds give or take and return 29 rows (this is fine). The new formulation runs in 0.077 seconds and gives the same result!

note that for the last row (in  ORDER BY Intervaldatetime order) LEAD will return null, so TIMESTAMPDIFF and the WHERE condition will be null, which is ok here but may need something changed if you use LEAD other places
